# Mongodb multiple date ranges

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection as below

```
{
    "Email" : "gg@gmail.com",
    "start" : ISODate("2015-11-09T12:00:00.000-06:30")
},


{
    "Email" : "aa@gmail.com",
    "start" : ISODate("2015-11-09T12:00:00.000-06:30")
},

{
    "Email" : "adjkj@gmail.com",
    "start" : ISODate("2015-08-03T12:00:00.000-06:30")
},

{
    "Email" : "gg@gmail.com",
    "start" : ISODate("2016-01-15T12:00:00.000-06:30")
}
```

I want fetch all the emails that are 90 days old from today's date but doesn't exists in last 30 days.So in the above collection below 2 documents are 90 days old

```
{
    "Email" : "gg@gmail.com",
    "start" : ISODate("2015-11-09T12:00:00.000-06:30")
}


{
    "Email" : "aa@gmail.com",
    "start" : ISODate("2015-11-09T12:00:00.000-06:30")
}
```

However "Email" : "gg@gmail.com" exists in last 30 days (see last document above), so the output should be

```
{
    "Email" : "aa@gmail.com",
    "start" : ISODate("2015-11-09T12:00:00.000-06:30")
}
```

Comment: Why is  `"adjkj@gmail.com"` not in the result?

Comment: Because it is greater than 90 days. I am looking for exact 90 days

Comment: If you want exactly 90 days, none of your documents matches.

Comment: Edited dates.I am querying on records that are output for below query db.testing.find({'start' :{'$gte': new Date(ISODate().getTime()-91*24*60*60*1000),$lte:new Date(ISODate().getTime()-90*24*60*60*1000) }},{_id:0,Email:1,start:1})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the aggregation query to achieve this:

The match condition is (find all docs with `start date 90 days old` and `not present in the last 30 days`).

```
db.Testing.aggregate([
    {'$group': {
        '_id': '$Email',
        'start': {'$addToSet' : '$start'}}}, //Consolidating docs
    {'$match' : {
        '$and': [
            {'start' :{'$not': {'$gte':  new Date(ISODate().getTime()-30*24*60*60*1000) }}}, //Removing docs where the date exists in the last 30 days.
            {'start' :{'$eq':  new Date(ISODate().getTime()-90*24*60*60*1000) }}
        ]}}
])
```

I am assuming you want docs that are exactly 90 days old. If it's for document that are older than 90 days just replace the `$eq` to with `$lte`.

Comment: {'start' :{'$eq':  new Date(ISODate().getTime()-90*24*60*60*1000) }} in the match will not work for me as I do have time stamp in the start field so I tried to replace that condition with something like this 'start' :{'$gte': new Date(ISODate().getTime()-91*24*60*60*1000),$lte:new Date(ISODate().getTime()-90*24*60*60*1000) } but even that is not working.

Comment: It's working on my side. btw the difference between `2015-11-08` and today's date is not 90 days.

Comment: Ya I have records in DB for the entire 11/2015 so shouldn't be a problem still not working as timestamp is there and $eq is trying to match exact timestamp

Comment: No I meant the change you suggested is working on my setup. Maybe try giving partial condition i.e. only `gte` then only `lte` to check what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Trying separately gives expected result so I tried something like this {'start' :{'$gte': new Date(ISODate().getTime()-90*24*60*60*1000),$lte:new Date(ISODate().getTime()-90*24*60*60*1000) } } . This shouldn't fetch any results since $gte and $lte has same condition still it fetch some results.

Comment: That's expected result. Using both `lte` and `gte` on the same value is equivalent to using `eq` and will match any value that's equal to `new Date(ISODate().getTime()-90*24*60*60*1000)`.

Comment: I used a different version of this and it fulfilled my purpose.Thanks.